# Wrapping SASS's @include in a shorthand macro

Tags: css, sass

I would like to be able to wrap SASS's `@include` in a shorthand such as `@i` for convenience.

Is this possible?  What's the best way to go about doing this?

```
#foo {
  @include rounded(3px);
}
```

Becomes:

```
#foo {
  @i rounded(3px);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask yourself: is this worth it? It doesn't seem like a lot of convenience and it'll probably take more effort than it's worth.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a quick & sane way to do it.  If not, I'll probably just map a hotkey in my editor.

Comment: @Dylan, I can definitely see a purpose for this.

Comment: Its a bit of an effort but you could write a plugin with PostCSS to convert @i to @include, then place the output of that into your SCSS parsing function (gulp/grunt/webpack/etc) to finish the compiling process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the Sass syntax, you can just use `+`:

```
#foo
  +rounded(3px)
```